# In Ubuntu how do I delete a directory and everything underneath it?

Tags: ubuntu

In Ubuntu how do I delete a directory and everything underneath it, including directories and their contents?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you are describing is called a *recursive remove*.  To do this, open a shell and type:

`rm -r /path/to/directory`

Comment: brilliant. worked first time!

Comment: ...and don't run this as root unless you *really* need to, and if you do, be very careful, especially if you add the '-f' option.

Answer (score 4):

```
cd parent-directory_of_folder_to_be_blasted
rm -r the_folder_that_needs_to_be_blasted
```

Answer (score 3):

**rmdir:** The rmdir command will delete an empty directory. To delete a directory and all of its contents recursively, use **rm -r** instead.